# d3 choropleth map - proper domain/range config

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am currently working on a d3 choropleth map. I am more specifically working to configure the scale based on incoming data.
I have two middle data points expressing where to set the color separation.

For example, I have the domain of [0,1]. Color scale of 3 elements, ['#FF9489', '#FFED89', '#83F5A2'](red, yellow, green). The data point given to divide the colors properly are good_bound, bad_bound(green = good, red = bad). good_bound = 0.9, bad_bound = 0.8. I want the map to show bound(red) < 0.8, 0.8 <= bound(yellow) < 0.9, 0.9 < bound(green).

I am understanding that the range method called off of d3.scale.quantize(this is the method I am using instead of threshold) works off of the domain given and range specified, dividing it evenly.

```
options.color = ['#FF9489', '#FFED89', '#83F5A2']
var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain([1,0].concat())
  .range(options.color.concat().reverse().slice(0, 3))
```

Right now I am only able to get it to work by passing in the domain as [good_bound,bad_bound] and it ends up with a domain of .8 to .9, which is obviously not what is required. I was trying to figure out a way to override the d3.scale.range method but I am not understanding the structure.

The end correct result needs to be 0%-80% - red, 80%-90% - yellow, 90%-100% - green.

I am not sure what other code snippets I might need to include without it being irrelevant to the issue, please let me know and I can include it.

Answer (score 0):

Scales domains aren't limited to two inputs.  If you want to map ranges you just specify them out:

```js
var options = {};
options.color = ['red', 'yellow', 'green'];
var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain([80,90,101])
  .range(options.color);
                 
console.log('0 is red - ' + colorScale(0));
console.log('50 is red - ' + colorScale(50));
console.log('80 is yellow - ' + colorScale(80));
console.log('88 is yellow - ' + colorScale(88));
console.log('90 is green - ' + colorScale(90));
console.log('95 is green - ' + colorScale(95));
console.log('100 is green - ' + colorScale(100));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: would it be necessary to define domain as [0,80,90,101] then?

Comment: @smoke, it's not necessary, anything <80 is red.